# How do I get out of grub rescue when the USB ports won't work?

Tags: boot, usb, grubrescue

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on an old HP compaq 7600. When I switched it on today, it booted to a black screen with the following message at the top:

```
Error: symbol not found: 'grub_register_command_prio'.
Grub rescue>
```

On top of this, none of the USB ports seem to be working now and so I can't even use my keyboard to type anything to get out of grub rescue.

What is the problem here and how can I fix GRUB to boot Ubuntu again?

Comment: Try plugging your keyboard into other USB ports. Maybe even rebooting a few times might bring that back to life. Check your BIOS settings whether USB support is enabled there and whether there are other settings like Legacy USB support that could help.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I tried all of the USB ports and tried rebooting but it went back to the same screen. I then tried resetting the bios but that's now left me stuck on the bios screen unable to choose any of the options as the computer still won't recognise the USB keyboard.

Comment: Does it have a PS/2 socket where you could plug a keyboard in? Can you verify that your keyboard is not broken?

Comment: Just checked the keyboard in another computer and it works fine.

Comment: The keyboard definitely works, I just can't figure out why the USB ports don't seem to be working.